# Chess board drop down menu should be on top, not under the right panel

Tags: bug, status-completed

As you can see in the screenshot, the drop down menu appears under the right panel, while it should be on top of it.

> [image]

I'm on Firefox 43.0.4/Windows 7.

Comment: Confirmed, yeah, that's ugly; looking at it

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's a fun combination of z-index and stacking-contexts (apparently; it really isn't my area - the team don't let me near UIs very often... not since *the incident*). Anyway, this should be fixed after the next deploy (which usually happens every few hours).

Comment: It's fixed, but I notice that the menu is slightly transparent. Would it make more sense for it to be completely opaque?

Comment: @nhahtdh I'll put that question to whoever made it transparent in the first place